# Deploying SharePoint files (css, javascript) onto different platforms without SharePoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I need to deploy to "_catalogs/masterpage/" and "Style Library/" multiple jpg, css, javascript files
These files originate from a developer platform and are to be deployed to multiple platforms without using SharePoint Designer.
Apart from manually uploading multiple files in the /Forms/AllItems.aspx pages, is there another way to do this ?

I'm using SharePoint 2007

Comment: I think this belongs on the [Sharepoint.SE] StackExchange.

Answer (score 0):

This is the exact purpose for [solution packages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa543214%28v=office.12%29.aspx):

> The Windows SharePoint Services solution framework provides a way to bundle all the components for extending Windows SharePoint Services in a new file that is called a solution file. A solution file has a .CAB-based format but a .WSP extension. A solution is a deployable, reusable package that can contain a set of Features, site definitions, and assemblies that apply to sites, and that you can enable or disable individually. You can use the solution file to deploy the contents of a Web Part package, including assemblies, class resources, .dwp files, and other package components.

The two recommended tools for creating solution packages for SharePoint 2007 are [WSPBuilder](http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/) and [STSDEV](http://stsdev.codeplex.com/).